# Functional vs non-Functional loops in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

What I want to do is return an array of objects based a dynamic size, I feel like I might be doing this in an overly complicated way but i’m also trying to do things in a more functional manner these days.

Here is how I would do it in the non-functional manner

```js
function nonFunctional(size) {
  let foo = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    foo.push({ bar: "baz" });
  }

  return foo;
}
```

Here is how i’m trying to do it in a Functional manner

```js
function functional(size) {
  return [...new Array(size)].map(() => {
    return {
      bar: 'baz'
    }
  });
}
```

1. Is this the best way to do this in a functional way?
2. What are some advantages/disadvantages of doing it this way vs the "traditional" way?
3. Is this really even functional programming related?

Comment: `return Array(size).fill({ bar: "baz" });`

Comment: Your code isn't functional, because you pass a thunk to `map`, i.e. a function without arguments. In FP in conjunction with a strict evaluated language explicit thunks are only used to obtain lazyness. Also in Javascript with its lack of a type system and the guarantees such a system entails, you can apply mutations locally, so that they are not observable in the parent scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'd do (not necessarily better):

   ```
     return Array.from({ length: size }, () => ({ bar: "baz" }));
   ```
2. Your functional way is less readable (IMO), and it creates two unnecessary intermediate arrays (the engine *might* optimize it away, but ... well *might*)
3. "functional / imperative programming" is not black and white. Code can be rather functional or rather imperative or purely functional, but all that depends on the one you ask.

Comment: thanks for the reply, not sure why everything was getting downvoted though. As for readability that was one of my concerns but i think i like what you said. This is likely the best response i'll get. Thanks again

Comment: @jeffbeltran it could count as opinionated / too broad and could be seen off-topic. SO is democratic after all, two people think that the answer is inappropriate, three think that it is apprppriate (or is that your upvote ;)), the majority wins :)

Comment: `Array.from(Array(size), ...)` will be more clear to those that aren't familiar with JS's odd "array-like" behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a great start by identifying that this behavior should be isolated in its own function. But "functional" isn't limited to common methods like `map`, `reduce` and `filter`.

Consider `buildArray` below -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x
  
const buildArray = (size = 0, f = identity) =>
  size === 0
    ? []
    : [ ...buildArray(size - 1, f), f(size - 1) ]
    
console.log(buildArray(5))
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

console.log(buildArray(5, x => x * x))
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 16 ]

console.log(buildArray(3, () => ({ a: 1 })))
// [ { a: 1 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 1 } ]

console.log(buildArray())
// []
```

Comment: this is amazing thank you. while my example was very contrived that last bit is what i was actually trying to do.